# Como fazer um temporizador decrescente em nodejs

Tags: javascript

A minha intenção é fazer um temporizador decrescente em javascript, mesmo que ninguém esteja no site o temporizador continua a contar descrentemente.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Pode ser com Nodejs mesmo.

Comment: Então, quando tiver um código de como tentou, com algum problema ou dúvida, você pode editar sua pergunta, [mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Já agora, se quiser fazer em javascript consigo, desde que alguém esteja sempre no site correto?

Comment: Só para reforçar: [MVCE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

> *"temporizador decrescente em javascript, mesmo que ninguém esteja no site o temporizador continua a contar descrentemente"*

Porquê usar um temporizador então? podes usar a data atual e decidir o que fazer. Por exemplo, tendo em conta as cores:

```
var cores = ['#faa', '#afa', '#aaf'];
```

podes então saber quantos minutos de um tal dia já passaram e fazer algumas contas...

```
var agora = new Date();
var minutosEsteDia = (agora.getHours() * 60) + agora.getMinutes();
var meiasHoras = minutosEsteDia / 30;
var cor = Math.round(meiasHoras % (cores.length - 1));
```

Agora deu -me a posição `2`, ie: `#aaf`. Vamos ver o que dá daqui a meia hora :)